# WooCommerce Shop Page Endpoint. No Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to add an endpoint for the shop page using this code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_city_endpoint' );
function add_city_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'city', EP_PAGES );
}
```

to get products filtered when url is something like: **/shop/city/new-york/**

But I get page with no products.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you looked at this page? Are you sure you need to do that as an action? What version of WC are you using?

Comment: @Difster, when I go to "site.com/shop/city/new-york/" I get a usual shop page (not 404) but with empty content. I'd like to have pretty urls for each city and I thought the endpoints would be the easiest way to achieve this. The WC version is 2.6.14. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I'll answer my own question.

Since the shop page is not an actual wordpress page, but an archive page for "product" post type, the endpoints don't work well for my purpose. And the proper way would be to use add_rewrite_rule instead:

```
add_action( 'init', 'city_add_rewrite_rules' );
function city_add_rewrite_rules() {

    $shop_page = ( $shop_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) && get_post( $shop_page_id ) ? get_page_uri( $shop_page_id ) : 'shop';

    add_rewrite_tag( '%sr_city%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule(
            "^$shop_page/city/([^/]+)/?$", 'index.php?post_type=product&sr_city=$matches[1]', 'top'
    );
    //pagination
    add_rewrite_rule(
            "^$shop_page/city/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$", 'index.php?post_type=product&sr_city=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top'
    );

}
```